# Power Profile (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, battery, plasma-5

I was wondering if there any way to add power profile in KUbuntu?

I know it's available on Ubuntu(GNOME) As an extension  but i want it on KDE.
Gnome extension : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/

Comment: Post the extension link by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1173716/edit) your question.

Comment: what do you mean by extension link??

Comment: What do you mean by "it's available on Ubuntu(GNOME) As an extension"? Which extension?

Comment: this one : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/